# why my gem is not found although it exists in the forge?

Tags: chef-infra, gemfile, test-kitchen

During a kitchen verify :
[image]

```
$ cat test/integration/advanced/serverspec/Gemfile   
source 'https://rubygems.org'   
gem 'net-ssh', '3.2.0'
```

Comment: but it installs it ....

`users on this machine.   
Could not find gem 'net-ssh (= 3.2.0)' in any of the gem sources listed in your
Gemfile.   
Don't run Bundler as root. Bundler can ask for sudo if it is needed, and   
installing your bundle as root will break this application for all non-root   
users on this machine.   
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.........    
Resolving dependencies...    
Using bundler 1.17.1    
Fetching net-ssh 3.2.0    
Installing net-ssh 3.2.0    
Bundle complete! 1 Gemfile dependency, 2 gems now installed.`

Comment: so this error-message seems false